# Поиск в выпадающем списке WooCommerce (WP)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить на сайт WordPress в оформление заказа поле с ПОИСКОМ по станциям метро.
Я использую плагин Saphali WC Lite, там добавила checkbox и соотвественно список, но вот как допилить поиск в плагин не понимаю.
Поделитесь своим опытом и знанием!

Comment: А зачем чекбокс? Как должен работать поиск?

Comment: Выпадающий список станций, а сверху вводят наименование, когда ввели первые буквы список показывает 2 записи. Например на Циане, где надо вести адрес. Авиаселс, вести город.

Comment: Там не надо ни списка ни чекбокса. Надо добавить обычный текстовый инпут. Дальше всё делается на js. Можно взять например это https://professorweb.ru/my/javascript/jquery/level4/4_5.php

Comment: Я делала это с помощью плагина, потому что форма отправляется письмом при оформлении заказа. Разве отработает просто текстовый инпут? Или надо как то внести корректировки в сам плагин?

Comment: С помощью плагина и добавить инпут. Думаю, что в нем должна быть такая возможность если можно добавить список

Comment: список можно, но не поиск)

Comment: Это называется не поиск, а автодополнение. И, как я уже сказал, тут нужно простое текстовое поле и никак не список